# Последовательность выполнения JS

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код JS:

```
var first = "";
var second = "";
init_vars();
dosomething(first, second);
```

2 пустые переменные. Функция `init_vars();` вносит в них значения.

Затем эти значения передаются в функцию `dosomething(first, second)`.

Основной код конечно не такой, но смысл такой же.

У меня получается что при выполнении переменные остаются пустыми и в функцию `dosomething(first, second);` они пустыми и попадают.

Если сделать тоже самое в цикле, в первый раз в функцию `dosomething(first, second);` попадут пустые переменные, но на второй раз в них уже будет информация.

Мой вопрос таков : **Как мне добиться "правильной" последовательности исполнения?**

Чтобы сначала выполнилась функция `init_vars();`, данные внеслись в переменные. А уж потом выполнилась функция `dosomething(first, second);`

Comment: вероятно, у Вас в init что-то асинхронное...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант с проверками через setTimeout, если по какой-то причине изменение значений переменных от вас не зависит:

```js
var first;
var second;

async_init_vars();

var attempts = 0;
setTimeout(function bubu(){
  if( ++attempts > 50 ) {
    // Если уже было много попыток, но значения так и не прилетели - пора остановиться.
    return console.log("Не дождались переменных first | second");
  }

  if( typeof first == "undefined" || typeof second == "undefined" ){
    // Если любая из переменных оказывается undefined, повторяем попытку чуть позже
    console.log("Переменные еще не готовы!");
    setTimeout(bubu, 200);
  } else {
    // Иначе запускаем основную функцию
    doSomething(first, second);
  }
}, 200);

/******/

function async_init_vars(){
  setTimeout(function asyncExample(){
    first = "bubu-1";
    second = "bubu-2";
  }, 1000);
}

function doSomething(a, b){
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

Даже если это у вас сработает (а оно сработает), всё равно костыльненько... Нужно посмотреть код init_vars, и в нем что-то поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Этого уже добились:

```js
var first = "";
var second = "";
init_vars();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  dosomething(first, second);
}

function init_vars() {
  first = "One";
  init_vars2();
}
function init_vars2() {
  second = "Two";
}
function dosomething(first, second) {
  console.log(first, second);
}
```

---

> при первом исполнении цикла ...

Я не вижу в вопросе никакого "цикла".

Comment: Но оно так и не работает.
Если точнее, то `init_vars()` определяет `first`, затем `init_vars()` вызывает ещё одну функцию, допустим `init_vars2()`, которая определяет `second`. А в остальном всё написано ровно так же как вы написали. Но почему-то всегда при первом исполнении цикла в `dosomething` уходят пустые переменные.

Comment: @bully Наверное, с трех попыток я смогу угадать, что у Вас в коде делается, но будет проще, если Вы его покажете - минимальный пример, который воспроизводит наблюдаемое поведение.